# Close modal without commit listner

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I need to identify if a Bootstrap modal was hide, but just when the form inside it was not submitted, I tried using:

```
$('#ModalID').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {});
```

But it is fired even when the commit is made. I need just when is cancelled, or cliked outside the modal, or even in close button. There is any way to identify it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if modal is open, alert dialog will show true.

```
alert($('#ModalID').hasClass('in'));
```

Comment: yes, but if I close the modal submitting the form, it turn to false too, I need to fire the event only if the modal is closed without submitting the form.